# GTK Themes Doesn't Work Well on Loki

Tags: themes, gtk

themes that I want to apply on my PC don't work as they should. I put the theme folder into the folder `/home/firat/.themes/` that I created before. Then I use Tweak Tool software to apply it. But it looks like this:
[image: myPc]
instead of this:
[image]

I tried with other themes but result is still same. Is this a bug or something or am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to put the theme folder in home/.local/share/themes.
Or maybe that theme doesn't support Pantheon DE.
And i recomend you to use [elmentary tweaks](https://launchpad.net/elementary-tweaks) for manage your desktop theme and some other things in elementary os.
Sorry for my bad english. Hope this answer help you!

Comment: I tried it with elementary tweaks, by putting the theme folder `/.local/share/themes.` but still doesn't work. I just don't get it. It was happened to me when I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Not all themes are going to display well in elementary, particularly in apps that have client side decorations like those native to elementary - files, maya, epiphany, etc.

You going through the right process to implement the theme, you just need to play around with different themes until you find one that works. Good luck!

Comment: Got it. But what I see is there are many people who have been able to do it. I'm wondering if my PC isn't compatible for setting themes. Is it possible?

Comment: I would suggest searching specifically for themes that are compatible with elementary. there are a few. just keep in mind, in general, elementary isn't as friendly to theming as some other distros.

Comment: Right. But look at this: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihxwpOAnRjU).This guy perfectly applies theme called Numix on Loki, Although I followed all the steps I couldn't. Anyway, as you sad I'm gonna look for a compatible theme.